# angular bootstrap div width not showing full only on ipad

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have 2 columns in a single Row. Its working fine but on IPAD its not showing full width.

MY CODE

```
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-sm-12">
            <div class="card mb-4">
              <div class="card-header">
                <div class="card-title-wrap bar-info">
                  <div class="card-title">Personal Information</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="card-block">
                  <div class="align-self-center halfway-fab text-center">
                    <a class="profile-image">
                      <img src="assets/img/portrait/medium/avatar-m-9.jpg"
                        class="rounded-circle img-border gradient-summer width-100" alt="Card image">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <span class="font-medium-2 text-uppercase">{{selectedPatient?.patientName}}</span>
                    <p class="grey font-small-2"></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row align-self-center">
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                      <ul class="no-list-style pl-0 text-center">
                        <li class="mb-2">
                          <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                            <div class="d-inline-block">
                              <span class="text-bold-500 primary"><a><i class="ft-briefcase font-small-3"></i>
                                  ID: </a></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-inline-block">
                              <span class="">
                                <span class="display-block overflow-hidden">
                                  &nbsp;&nbsp;{{selectedPatient?.mrn}}</span>

                              </span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="mb-2">
                          <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                            <div class="d-inline-block">
                              <span class="text-bold-500 primary"><a><i class="ft-briefcase font-small-3"></i>
                                  Case #:</a></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-inline-block">
                              <span class="">
                                <span class="display-block overflow-hidden"> &nbsp;&nbsp;Ninja Developer</span>

                              </span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                      <ul class="no-list-style pl-0 text-center">
                        <li class="mb-2">
                          <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                            <div class="d-inline-block">
                              <span class="text-bold-500 primary"><a><i class="ft-briefcase font-small-3"></i>
                                  Age:</a></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-inline-block">
                              <span class="">
                                <span
                                  class="display-block overflow-hidden">&nbsp;&nbsp;{{selectedPatient?.age}}</span>

                              </span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="mb-2">
                          <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                            <div class="d-inline-block">
                              <span class="text-bold-500 primary"><a><i class="ft-briefcase font-small-3"></i>
                                  Contact Number:</a></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-inline-block">
                              <span class="">
                                <span
                                  class="display-block overflow-hidden">&nbsp;&nbsp;{{selectedPatient?.phone}}</span>

                              </span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                      <ul class="no-list-style pl-0 text-center">
                        <li class="mb-2">
                          <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                            <div class="d-inline-block">
                              <span class="text-bold-500 primary"><a><i class="ft-briefcase font-small-3"></i>
                                  Address:</a></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-inline-block">
                              <span class="">
                                <span
                                  class="display-block overflow-hidden">&nbsp;&nbsp;{{selectedPatient?.address}}</span>

                              </span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                      <ul class="no-list-style pl-0 text-center">
                        <li class="mb-2">
                          <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                            <div class="d-inline-block">
                              <span class="text-bold-500 primary"><a><i class="ft-briefcase font-small-3"></i>
                                  Email:</a></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-inline-block">
                              <span class="">
                                <span
                                  class="display-block overflow-hidden">&nbsp;&nbsp;{{selectedPatient?.email}}</span>

                              </span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
          <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
            <!--About div starts-->
            <div id="about">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                      <div class="card-title-wrap bar-info">
                        <div class="card-title">Shedule Appoinment</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <div class="card-block">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                          <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                            <div class="d-inline-block">
                              <span class="text-bold-500 primary"><a><i class="ft-briefcase font-small-3"></i>
                                  DR Micky:</a></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-inline-block">
                              <span class="">
                                <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;7 Feb</span>

                              </span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <span class="display-block overflow-hidden">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
                            printing and typesetting industry.
                          </span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div id="about">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                      <div class="card-title-wrap bar-info">
                        <div class="card-title">Medication</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <div class="card-block">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                          <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                            <div class="d-inline-block">
                              <span class="text-bold-500 primary"><a><i class="ft-briefcase font-small-3"></i>
                                  Lisinoril 1 in tab:</a></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-inline-block">
                              <span class="">
                                <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Feb 1, 2020</span>

                              </span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                            <div class="d-inline-block">
                              <span class="text-bold-500 primary"><a><i class="ft-briefcase font-small-3"></i>
                                  Lisinoril 1 in tab:</a></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-inline-block">
                              <span class="">
                                <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Feb 1, 2020</span>

                              </span>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                        </div>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Its showing full width on all devices but on IPAD only its leaving some white space so my text is coming out I need to show full width in this so it can cover whole area in white.
I try to give it like this col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-sm-12 but its also not working.

Answer (score 0):

Just change second line with below and it will work!

```
<div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
```